# ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Network issues on working wireless

Tags: networking, wireless

In have an issue with my network. When I'm working with wire connection everything is fine, but when i switch to connection over wifi, my internet connection is really slow, ping losts packets to router gateway (~ 60% loss).
I am sure that my wifi router is fine, but others devices connected via wifi works fine.

result of iwconfig

```
vmnet8    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"netis"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 04:8D:38:03:23:10   
      Bit Rate=300 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-34 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:17   Missed beacon:0

vmnet1    no wireless extensions.
```

Wireless info
http://textuploader.com/dcnaj

Answer (score 1):

We see this in your paste:

```
Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'netis' [AC1]>
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-21 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"netis"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000023748417e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 700ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : TKIP CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. In some cases, auto B and G may also be helpful. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a problem by adding those lines

```
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
blacklist brcm80211
```

to

```
 /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```